# How to do long division of 5555 / 55

Tags: arithmetic

I know this might seem silly, but I am having trouble performing step-by-step long division on $5555 \div 55$.

My main problem is that I don't know when or what the rule is about putting the zeroes. I end up with eleven the way I was taught to calculate it.

Comment: "Bring down" the digits **one at a time**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional grade-school algorithm:

```
              101  
             ----  
          55)5555  
             55  
             ---  
               5  
               0  
               --  
               55  
               55  
               --
```

Comment: At what point did you put the zero in?

Comment: Oh I see, 55 goes into 0 no times. Then you brought down the next 5...

Comment: @Imray: That’s right. I just did it one digit at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps seeing it this way would give you an idea:

$$5555 = 5500 + 55 = 55*???$$

**Further hint**

$$5555 = 5500 + 55 = 55 \cdot 100 + 55 \cdot 1 = 55 \cdot ???$$

Comment: huh? I don't understand what you are getting at

Comment: @Imray see the edited version with another hint.

Comment: I know what the answer is, I do own a calculator. My question was about the process.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a calculator. Note that the decomposition itself implies (because 5500 has 2 zeroes on the right) that you need an extra 0 in division. That comes from bringing things down 1 at a time as was suggested by a couple of people. I tried to explain to you not mechanically where the 0 comes from, but really what happens when you do division - and this is the where the extra 0 really comes from...